# Construct a homeomorphism from $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ such that $f(0)= p$

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

$D^n=\{(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)\in \Bbb R^n|x_1^2+\dotsc+x_n^2\geq1\}$, and  $p\in \Bbb R^n \setminus D^n$

Construct a [homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism) $f\colon\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ such that

a) $f$ is the identity map on $D^n$, and

b) $f(0)= p$

**What about If we replace homeomorphism to [Diffeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism)?**

---

Attempt at $n=1$, en. But how about $n\geq 2$?

Comment: If you have a solution for $n=1$, probably considering the distance in the more general case between $x$ and $p$ and the distance between $x$ and $D^n$ would be useful.

Comment: Do you want to write it down explicitly, or show that such a homeomorphism exists?

Comment: @davidlowryduda  write it down explicitly Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}x,&|x|\ge 1\\
x+(1-|x|)p,&|x|<1\end{cases}$$
?

This maps every straight line from $0$ to a point on the unit sphere to a straight line between $p$ and the same point on the unit sphere, and does so "at constant speed".